# Running Bash from Ruby with parentheses: unexpected token near '('

Tags: ruby, git, bash

I'm trying to write a Ruby script that does some simple git commands. I want to list all file changes that are not in my app directory.

Running the following to get all changes in terminal:

```
git ls-files -m
```

Yields:

```
config/environment.rb
app/models/site.rb
```

Running with a wildcard exception in terminal:

```
git ls-files -m !(app)
```

Yields:

```
config/environment.rb
```

Doing the same in Ruby using:

```
`git ls-files -m !(app)`
```

Yields:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `git ls-files -m !(app)'
```

I've tried to add double-escapes:

```
`git ls-files -m \\!\\(app\\)`
```

Yields no error but an empty result.

I've also tried using Shellwords:

```
require 'shellwords'
`git ls-files -m #{Shellwords.escape("!(app)")}`
```

Yields no error but an empty result.

Using the `%x[]` syntax behaves exactly like backticks as well, but does not seem to work as I'd like it to.

Any ideas how to get the same result from running `git ls-files -m !(app)` in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!(app)` is a bash extended glob. So there are two problems:

1. `ruby` uses `sh` to execute system commands, not `bash`. (You can see that in the error message, which claims to come from `sh:`.) However, since your `sh` is implemented by `bash`, you do have bash available, with one small problem: When `bash` is running as `sh`, it disables a lot of bash-specific features.
2. Even if it were `bash`, it is highly likely that `shopt -s extglob` has not been executed, which is necessary for `!(app)` and other extended globs to work. Extended globs are not enabled by default, but some distributions (ubuntu, for example) enable them in order to implement tab completions, so you probably have them enabled in your interactive shell. However, since ruby is not invoking an interactive shell, it's quite likely that the bash startup file with the `shopt -s extglob` command hasn't been executed.

None of that makes it impossible to use the command through ruby, but it certainly complicates life. For example, one possible workaround would be to enable BASHOPTS and force `bash` to run:

```
`env BASHOPTS=$BASHOPTS:extglob bash -c 'git ls-files -m !(app)'`
```

which might be more complicated than the alternative solution of filtering out the unwanted directory names using `grep -v`.

Setting `BASHOPTS` using `env` will actually only work if you `/bin/sh` is really `bash`, so it would probably be better to so the `shopt` directly in the executed command. That's straight-forward, but there is a small wrinkle; you need to introduce a newline between the `shopt` command and the use of extended glob, because bash tokenizes commands a line at a time (and if `extglob` is not set when it tokenizes, the `(` is a metacharacter.)

This seems to work:

```
`bash -c "shopt -s extglob\ngit ls-files -m !(app)"`
```

Comment: Interesting info for sure... is there a way to change the shell (to bash from sh) within Ruby, and import this extension?

Comment: @DavidElner: You can use `system` to invoke any program you like (by giving it a list instead of a string). And I found a message on some userlist once which claimed that you could redefine the backtick (in the Kernel module: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60). That's about all I know; I don't do much ruby.

Comment: @DavidElner: Now that I looked at the docs, I think calling `system` would be your best bet; you would supply `"/bin/bash", "-c", "....your command...."` as arguments. You would probably need to set `BASHOPTS` by creating an `env` argument to the `system` call. And you could presumably redefine Kernel.#\` to do that. But as I said, I'm not much of a Ruby programmer. Good luck.

Comment: I took your snippet and threw it in a function. Slightly hackish, but seems to work well enough:
`def shell(command)
  `env BASHOPTS=$BASHOPTS:extglob bash -c '#{command}'`
end`

Comment: @DavidElner: I think the `system` call is going to be the cleanest. Also, I added a better hackish snippet, which uses `shopt` instead of playing around with `BASHOPTS` (which might not exist).